# Custom block admin page

Tags: 8, blocks

I'm trying to build a module to create a custom admin page to manage a custom block. I would like to include the block content field and a checkbox to enable or disable the block.

Is this possible or should I just build a block that prints the body value from a basic page? So for example, I could just build a page and my module would enable the block depending on whether or not the page is published. So a user could edit the copy and then publish the page when he/she needs the block to appear.

Comment: Is the only thing in your block the body field? Why not add the published checkbox to the block and let editors edit the block?

Comment: Yes, it's just the body field. That sounds like a good solution, thanks.